# Can't seem to match input with values in a text file

Tags: c, loops

This is what the items.txt contains:

```
275,Fresh Fish,12.34,0
386,Soft kleenex,45.67,1
240,Ultra Tide,24.34,1
916,Red Apples,123.45,0
385,Magic Broom,456.78,1
495,Liquid Soap,546.02,1
316,Chocolate Cookies,78.34,1
355,Organic Milk,24.34,0
846,Dark Chocolate,123.45,1
359,Organic Banana,99.99,0
```

How can I rewind the file when user enters "Y"? It works if I enter the right value the first time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAX (0.13)
void keybFlush(){
   while(getchar() != '\n');
}
int getInt(){
   int val;
   char nl = 'x';
   while (nl != '\n'){
      scanf("%d%c", &val, &nl);
      if (nl != '\n'){
         keybFlush();
         printf("Invalid Integer, please try again: ");
      }
   }
   return val;
}
int yes(){
   char ch = 'x';
   int res;
   do{
      ch = getchar();
      res = (ch == 'Y' || ch == 'y');
      keybFlush();
   } while (ch != 'y' && ch != 'Y' && ch != 'n' && ch != 'N' && printf("Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable: "));
   return res;
}
int main(){
   int upc, userUpc, found = 0;
   double price;
   int isTaxed, i;
   char item[21], ch, x, y;
   FILE* fptr = fopen("items.txt", "r");
   if (fptr){
   do {
   userUpc=getInt();
printf(" UPC  | Name               |   Price   |   Tax   |   Total\n"
       " -----+--------------------+-----------+---------+-----------\n");
   printf("its : %d\n", userUpc);
   while (!feof(fptr)){
      fscanf(fptr, "%d,%[^,],%lf,%d", &upc, item, &price, &isTaxed);
      if ( upc == userUpc){
         if(!feof(fptr)){
            printf("%-6d|%-20s|%11.2lf|", upc, item, price);
            if (isTaxed)
               printf("%9.2lf|%11.2lf\n", price * TAX, price * (1+TAX));
            else
               printf("%9.2lf|%11.2lf\n", 0.0, price);
            found = 1;
         }
      }
   }
   if (!found){
      printf("Can't find any matched records\n");
   }
   printf("Do you want to continue: ");
   i=yes();  // if yes, rewind the file
   } while (!userUpc || (i == 1));
   fclose(fptr);

   }
   else{
      printf("could not open the file\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

If I enter "y" to continue and the right value, it doesn't seem to output correctly.

Comment: `i=yes();` --> `if(i=yes())rewind(fptr);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY is using a function that was originally for magnetic tape files.  A more generic method is to use the fseek() function.

Comment: @user3629249 see **7.19.9.5 The rewind function 2** of [n1256.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

Comment: The code has undefined behavior as `printf(..., upc, item, price);` is not known to use valid values.  Need to check the result of `fscanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

To change the position of your file cursor to the beginning of the file:

```
fseek(filePtr, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

more on file manipulation :
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/File-Positioning.html